# Spring JPA query by Example using nested list property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with retriving by criteria (i can't change it), using nested list.
I need to use "by Example".

My Entity is:

```
public class CourseEntity implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "COURSE_ADMINISTRATOR",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ADMINISTRATOR_ID") }
    )
    private Set<AdministratorEntity> administratorList = new LinkedHashSet<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<InvitationEntity> invitationList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

public class AdministratorEntity extends CommonEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
}

public class InvitationEntity extends CommonEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private PersonEntity person;
}

public class PersonEntity extends CommonEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;
}
```

My code is:

```
CourseEntity example = this.mapper.to2Entity(to);

Optional.ofNullable(to.getStatus())
        .flatMap(status -> Optional.ofNullable(status.getId()))
        .ifPresent(value -> {
            CourseStatusEntity entity = new CourseStatusEntity();
            entity.setId(value);
            example.setStatus(entity);
        });

String userLoggedEmail = UserUtils.getMandatoryEmail();

// if admin...
if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(to.getUserType()) && this.isAdmin()){
    example.getAdministratorList().add(new AdministratorEntity().setEmail(userLoggedEmail));
}

// else user (default)
else{
    PersonEntity        personEntity        = new PersonEntity().setEmail(userLoggedEmail);
    InvitationEntity    invitationEntity    = new InvitationEntity().setPerson(personEntity);
    example.getInvitationList().add(invitationEntity);
}

Sort        sort        = ServiceUtils.createSort(to.getPagination());
Pageable    pageable    = PageRequest.of(to.getPagination().getPageNumber(), to.getPagination().getPageSize(), sort);

return this.repository.findAll(Example.of(example, ExampleMatcher.matchingAll().withIgnoreNullValues()), pageable);
```

the problem is that not use the userLoggedEmail added to list of root entity.

if user is an admin, I need to take all course where he is an admin, otherwise course where he are invitated.

actually is returning all data present into table and not filtering by userLoggedEmail